# I am trying to use mocha in angular 6 for testing and the following error comes, can test angular 6 using mocha

Tags: angular, angular6

```
/home/sachin/workstation/kitcode/kitcode-frontend-fork/src/app/login/login.component.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname)
```

import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Comment: My guess it the import needs to go before the function?

Answer (score 0):

import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

No extra { before import

Comment: There is no any extra {